# Flex AS3 - Inheritance and factory method

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, class, design-patterns, oop

Before asking my question I would like to explain little about my architecture.My data is of mixed types like String , Array Collection , Boolean I have to populate the data into appropriate UI component - for example Boolean to check box , Array to List...... so We have created a factory class which will return 3 different type of component based on the input argument

1. CTextfield -> extends mx.controls.Text
2. CList  ->  extends mx.controls.List
3. CCheckBox -> extends custom.MultiLineCheckBox

.

MultiLineCheckBox which extends mx.controls.CheckBox and few methods are overridden  to bring the multiple line label.

http://spy6.blogspot.com/2008/09/flex-multiline-checkbox.html

It works perfect.Am using the MultiLineCheckBox in the entire application wherever I want check Box.

Now I went into a scenario where I want check Box instead of MultiLineCheckBox. How to rewrite my CCheckBox  to handle MultiLineCheckBox  and also default CheckBox?

Note : Each of the CCheckBox class has lot of methods init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an abstract factory that extends from your concrete factory (http://cnx.org/content/m17203/latest/AbstractFactory.jpg) then write the logic of handle the different scenarios in it, when to use checkbox vs multilinecheckbox

Comment: @Anandh read the factory, inheritance and possible the MVC chapters in the book OReilly AS3 Design Pattern (http://www.amazon.ca/ActionScript-3-0-Design-Patterns-Programming/dp/0596528469)

Comment: AS3 doesn't support abstract features , read in some blog trying to force AS3 to have language features is error prone. Wat says?